# In EF6 how do I define my class to store a list of references instead of a list of objects?

Tags: database, vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

VS2103, EF6, MVC, VB

Still learning how code first works.  With the following Classes:

```
Public Class Order
  Public Property OrderID as Integer
  Public Property Products as new List(Of Product)
  .
  .
End Class

Public Class Product
  Public Property ProductID as Integer
  Public Property name as String
  .
  .
End Class

Public Class ApplicationDbContext
  Public Property Orders As DbSet(Of Order)
  Public Property Products As DbSet(Of Product)
End Class
```

When I executed the following:

```
db.Orders.Add(anOrder)
db.SaveChanges()
```

I ended up also adding records to the Products datatable.  So I get it that wasn't the way to define the Class Order.  I was trying to have a property in Order that would navigate to the individual Products that make up the order.  I mistakenly thought I was creating a list of references into Products, but obviously I was creating the need for the system to store Product records in the Products datatable.

What should I have coded so that I can peruse through the Products on an order by getting a reference into Products instead of adding to Products?  I apologize if I'm not asking the question well.

Best Regards,
Alan

Comment: You haven't shown nearly enough code here to determine what you did wrong.  Show your actual code.

Comment: @Erik - I'm sorry, I was trying to focus on the part I thought was relevant to my issue, but I will go back and figure out how to show the issue more clearly without printing a book on the page.  Thanks for the look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are working with disconnected entities as you mentioned MVC.

The culprit is this line of code...

```
db.Orders.Add(anOrder)
```

This line of code not only sets the entity state of the root entity (the instance of the Order class in this case) to Added but also sets the entity state of every object in the graph to Added.  When EF sees objects with an entity state of Added, it will issue INSERT statements for these objects.  If your object graph contains references to existing entities (such as instances of the Product class that have previously been persisted), it is your responsibility to set the entity state of each object in the graph appropriately.